# Parse Soap Response in PLSQL

Tags: xml, parsing, soap, plsql

I have the following response from the Soap Web Service call that is stored in a clob column.

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?><S:Envelope xmlns:S="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><S:Body><S:Fault xmlns:ns4="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope"><faultcode>S:Server</faultcode><faultstring>The customer order number/fulfill order number/source loc ID/fulfill loc ID combination already exists in ordcust.  Customer order no SA00469775049, Fulfill order no 1.</faultstring><detail><ns12:IllegalStateWSFaultException xmlns:ns9="http://www.oracle.com/retail/integration/base/bo/FulfilOrdCfmCol/v1" xmlns:ns8="http://www.oracle.com/retail/rms/integration/services/FulfillOrderService/v1" xmlns:ns7="http://www.oracle.com/retail/integration/base/bo/FulfilOrdDtl/v1" xmlns:ns6="http://www.oracle.com/retail/integration/base/bo/LocOfFulfilOrdCustDesc/v1" xmlns:ns5="http://www.oracle.com/retail/integration/custom/bo/EOfBrFulfilOrdCustDesc/v1" xmlns:ns4="http://www.oracle.com/retail/integration/localization/bo/BrFulfilOrdCustDesc/v1" xmlns:ns3="http://www.oracle.com/retail/integration/base/bo/FulfilOrdCustDesc/v1" xmlns:ns2="http://www.oracle.com/retail/integration/base/bo/FulfilOrdDesc/v1" xmlns:ns17="http://www.oracle.com/retail/integration/base/bo/InvocationSuccess/v1" xmlns:ns16="http://www.oracle.com/retail/integration/base/bo/FulfilOrdDtlRef/v1" xmlns:ns15="http://www.oracle.com/retail/integration/base/bo/FulfilOrdRef/v1" xmlns:ns14="http://www.oracle.com/retail/integration/base/bo/FulfilOrdColRef/v1" xmlns:ns13="http://www.oracle.com/retail/integration/base/bo/FulfilOrdColDesc/v1" xmlns:ns11="http://www.oracle.com/retail/integration/base/bo/FulfilOrdCfmDtl/v1" xmlns:ns10="http://www.oracle.com/retail/integration/base/bo/FulfilOrdCfmDesc/v1" xmlns:ns12="http://www.oracle.com/retail/integration/services/exception/v1"><ns12:shortErrorMessage>The customer order number/fulfill order number/source loc ID/fulfill loc ID combination already exists in ordcust.  Customer order no SA00469775049, Fulfill order no 1.</ns12:shortErrorMessage><ns12:errorDescription>com.oracle.retail.integration.services.exception.v1.IllegalStateWSFaultException
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor273.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at weblogic.wsee.jaxws.JAXWSServlet.doRequest(JAXWSServlet.java:99)
    at weblogic.servlet.http.AbstractAsyncServlet.service(AbstractAsyncServlet.java:99)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:820)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:227)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.invokeServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java:125)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:221)
</ns12:errorDescription><ns12:BusinessProblemDetail><ns12:problemDescription>The customer order number/fulfill order number/source loc ID/fulfill loc ID combination already exists in ordcust.  Customer order no SA00469775049, Fulfill order no 1.</ns12:problemDescription></ns12:BusinessProblemDetail></ns12:IllegalStateWSFaultException></detail></S:Fault></S:Body></S:Envelope>
```

I want the  tag at the very below of the XML to print.

How to I do that?

Comment: You will need to provide more information about your environment for somebody to help you.

Comment: You mean to give the Request Envelope ?